# How to count min,max in loop (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, while-loop, min

I have problem with coding 1 app for toomorow lectures.

So,
That program ask user for numbers, on typed "100" it's stops, and it shows:
-average
-min
-max

I know what kind of loop, i need to use (do-while right?).
But how i'm suppoused to count average,min,max without using arrays ?

Comment: show us some code. we dont make the work for you...

Comment: Do You really think We work for You...!!!

Comment: lol, no. I'm just asking how to aquire those things from loop without array, beacuse i have no idea, at the moment, and i have no code, only concept, my mind. Also i didn't except that some1 will do that for me. I need just tips for that or navigate me. -_-

Comment: In honesty, Minimum is easy, just keep a memory of the current lowest. Same with max. For average, total all numbers and divide by the number of numbers entered (so just keep a running total). Like what Azorius says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is shorthand pseudo code because you have to code this yourself:

```
min = max = total = user_input
count = 0
do {
    count++
    input = get_input
    total += input
    min or max maybe = input
} while (input !=100)
average = total / count
print stuff
```

good luck

Comment: Yeah, i know :) Thanks! That's what i needed, rest i will do with no problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Step 1 : user three temp variable 
Step 2 : initialize three temp variable(min,max,avg all by 0)
Step 1 : inside the loop if temp > max ==>> max = temp
Step 1 : inside the loop if temp < min ==>> min = temp
Step 1 : avg = ( avg + temp )/i

int[] values = { .. values .. }

int min=0,max=0,avg = 0;
for(int i=1;i<=values.length;i++)
{
if(min > values[i])
min = values[i] 
if(max < values[i])
max = values[i] 
avg = ( avg + values[i] ) / i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to calculate average min and max without arrays. I cannot, however tell you how to calculate average min and max WITH arrays.

Minimum is easy:

```
int current_min
ArrayList<int> find_min = new ArrayList<int>();
for (int c : find_min)
    if (c < current_min)
        current_min = c;
```

Maximum is a little bit harder. You need to use "functions"

```
boolean check_if_integer_is_bigger_than_another_integer(int another_integer_to_check_against, int the_original_integer_goes_here_into_this_argument_here)
{
    if (another_integer_to_check_against > the_original_integer_goes_here_into_this_argument_here)
    return (another_integer_to_check_against > the_original_integer_goes_here_into_this_argument_here) //Important
    return (another_integer_to_check_against > the_original_integer_goes_here_into_this_argument_here)
}
    int current_max
    ArrayList<int> find_max = new ArrayList<int>();
    for (int c : find_max)
        if (check_if_integer_is_bigger_than_another_integer(c, current_max))
            current_max = c;
```

I dont even want to go into averaging. You have to add numbers and I'm not exactly qualified for that.

Comment: awesome, much more elegant than and better researched than my solution!, you should use CarmelCase when using Java, but your level of verbosity is spot on!

Comment: Thanks. I really should focus harder on the whole "adding" thing. Maybe I'll pass kindergarten, if I'm lucky.

Comment: I think You have used array

Comment: Oh it seems I did let me just change that to a list: because this solution is TOTALLY LEGIT.

Comment: LOL this got best answer... amazing